# Can we rename the "Edit dependency "Label in opportunity for closed stage?

Tags: lightning, component, salespath

[Edit Dependency popup] Can we have an alternate approach for this question?

The requirement is to change the label of the standard "Edit dependency" popup which get displayed when we click on "Mark Stage as Completed".

Also, can we add custom text field inside the popup?

[Click to see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EcA5.png)

Comment: Could you share a screenshot? I am not sure to what you are referring.

Comment: Yess. Attach the screecshot

Comment: @SanderdeJong Can you please confirm whether this is feasible or out-of-the-box functionality?

Comment: Ah, now I see. I had never noticed that title, it is indeed a strange title. I do not know how to change that, I am 99% certain that you cannot change it. But maybe someone else knows how. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks @SanderdeJong